# Регулярка на поиск определенного числа в строке

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Всем  привет, есть задача требуется проверить соответствует ли строка вида x+y вот такому условию  :
***x(здесь любое число от 1 до 10)+(здесь любой арифметический знак)y(здесь любое число от 1 до 10)***.
Пытаюсь решить через регулярки :

```
String pattern = "^[1-9][+,\\-,/,*][1-9]$"; - обрабатывает все кроме 10
String pattern = "^[1-9]|[10][+,\\-,/,*][1-9]|[10]$"; - пропускает в том числе и 11, 12 и тд.
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
^([1-9]|10)[-/+*]([1-9]|10)$
```

[Пример работы](https://regex101.com/r/EKmftx/2).

Comment: Спасибо! Пропустил круглые скобки :/

Comment: @Artur, если ответ был полезен, поставьте зеленую галочку :)